# How to get keys from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm using Laravel. I have JSON returned from Database.
I would like to get key names like "id / name / email / revision" from following JSON.

```
{
    "id": "000",
    "records": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "hoge",
            "email": "Hoge@alk.jp",
            "revision": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "zaku",
            "email": "zaku@alk.jp",
            "revision": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

Please let me know how to get key names.
Thank you.

Comment: use `json_decode($json)`, then like a regular php array get values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the keys with `collection get key` by code following:

```
collect($data->records)->keys();
```

This will return

```
id
name
email
revision
```

More detail you can check here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keys

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to an array:

```
$array = josn_decode($jsonVariable, true);
```

Then use `foreach`:

```
foreach($array['records'][0] as $key => $value){
    $keys[] = $key;
}
```

or [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
array_keys($array['records']);
```

or [`collect`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#creating-collections) to get keys:

```
$keys = collect($array['records'])->keys();
```

Comment: No need to `foreach`--PHP has `array_keys` method